# What the difference between rds.DatabaseInstance and rds.IDatabaseInstance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cdk

What I want to do is here

- Making new RDS Aurora for Production
- Using already exist RDS Mysql for Staging
- I need to give these secret to ECS

My idea is here below,

Making `dbCluster` variable for storing both.

in Prod it store the `DatabaseCluster` and Stag it store `rds.DatabaseInstance`

This is my Staging environment

```js
    public readonly dbCluster: rds.DatabaseCluster | rds.DatabaseInstance; 
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
      const existingDatabaseInstance = rds.DatabaseInstance.fromDatabaseInstanceAttributes(this,'mysqlrds',{
        instanceIdentifier: "XXXXXXXXXX",
        securityGroups: [],
        instanceEndpointAddress: "XXXXXXXXXX.cishneowmf1a.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
        port: 3306
      });
```

then in another script.

I can give the secret to `ECS`, either it has `rds.DatabaseCluster` or `rds.DatabaseInstance`

```js
    export interface CdkStFargateStackProps extends StackProps {
      readonly dbCluster: rds.DatabaseCluster | rds.DatabaseInstance;
        props!.dbCluster.secret?.grantRead(taskDefinitionAdmin.taskRole)
```

The problems are

- `rds.DatabaseInstance.fromDatabaseInstanceAttributes`

returns `IDatabaseInstance` not `DatabaseInstance`.

- `IDatabaseInstance` doesn't have `secret`

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are the RDS MySQL instance's credentials stored in Secrets Manager?

Comment: Yes it is stored in Secret Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I solve this?

Return a read-only reference to the RDS MySQL's secret using the [Secret.fromSecretPartialArn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_secretsmanager.Secret.html#static-fromwbrsecretwbrpartialwbrarnscope-id-secretpartialarn) static method. Pass the secret's ARN without the random suffix letters.

`fromSecretPartialArn` returns a class that implements the [ISecret](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_secretsmanager.ISecret.html) interface.  It's the same type returned by the `DatabaseCluster.secret` property you are already using.  Use its `grantRead` method, which grants read access to an IAM principal such as your `taskDefinitionAdmin.taskRole`, using its principal policy or resource policy.

> What the difference between `rds.DatabaseInstance` and `rds.IDatabaseInstance`?

They belong to [different CDK categories](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/work-with.html#work-with-library):

`rds.DatabaseInstance` is a `Construct`, *Library classes that represent one or more concrete AWS resources*.

`rds.IDatabaseInstance` is an `Interface`, *whose names all begin with "I", define the absolute minimum functionality for the corresponding construct or other class. The CDK uses construct interfaces to represent AWS resources that are defined outside your AWS CDK app and referenced by methods such as Bucket.fromBucketArn().*

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand the `Ixxxx` meaning. It could be more useful to use the one same resource from multiple project. This basic idea explanation helps me.